# Express Throws "object is not a function" error with newest version of Express and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Running the following with node throws an "object is not a function" error, referencing "express()" specifically.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I thought that I just hadn't installed it (using express scriptName, then npm install), but doing that simply created the default app.js file, and didn't include my code at all.  Am I just not understanding the workflow here?  What am I missing?

```
node --version
v0.10.10

express --version
3.2.6
```

Comment: IT should work. This error eccurs when the express version is < 3.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing here, everything works fine.

Comment: What do you get from `require('express').version`? Maybe your command-line version is different from what Node picks up with `require`.

Comment: Do you have `express.js` file in your working directory by any chance (naming conflict)? This would be a reason.